# In salesforce, how to create two sync Objects having similar fields

Tags: apex, salesforce-lightning

How to Create two Objects say Obj1 and Obj2 having similar fields. On creating record of Obj1, associated Obj2 record should be created and vice versa. Additionally, updates should also be in sync i.e. updating the Obj1 should reflect in the Obj2  and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create both objects obj1 and obj2 with similar fields.
Now create Apex trigger on both objects with after insert and after update event as shown below.

```
trigger Obj1Trigger on obj1__c (after insert, after update) {
    list<obj2__c> recList = new list<obj2__c>();
    if(trigger.isAfter){
        
        if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate){
            
            for(obj1__c ob : Trigger.new){
                obj2__c obj2Rec = new obj2__c();
                obj2Rec.name = ob.name;
                obj2Rec.field1 = ob.field1;
                obj2Rec.field2 = ob.field2;
                obj2Rec.field3 = ob.field3;
                recList.add(obj2Rec);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Similarly create trigger for obj2.

You will also need a way to associate two object's records with each other.
There are two ways to associate the related records.

way1:

- identify two related records based on name field.
- for this you will need to keep the name field unique(no records in the object have same name).

way2:

- make one obj1 as parent and obj2 as child using master Detail relation ship field.

Answer (score 0):

Having two triggers on both objects without the necessary precaution will result in a recursion of triggers (infinite loop) and you'll get a **System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded**.

To avoid that, we can use a handler class with a flag which checks if one of the triggers has initiated the sync logic. The idea here is, we need to fire the trigger only once, upon a DML, and prevent the other trigger to fire until sync is complete.

- ***This solution only works for the insert sync. To sync on update,
  somehow we need to be able to check which fields were edited and send that info to our handler class.***

First, create a handler class with a static boolean initiated to false. This class will also have methods to perform the sync. Each method sets the flag to true so the other trigger won't try to sync.

```
public class HandleSync {
    public static Boolean recursion = false;
    
    public static void insert1(List<Obj2__c> newList) {

        List<Obj1__c> collectObj1 = new List<Obj1__c>();

        for (Obj2__c obj2 : newList) {
            Obj1__c obj1 = new Obj1__c();
            obj1.aField = obj2.aField;
            collectObj1.add(obj1);
        }
        //Raise the flag before the DML
        recursion = true;
        insert collectObj1;
    }

    public static void insert2(List<Obj1__c> newList) {

        List<Obj2__c> collectObj2 = new List<Obj2__c>();

        for (Obj1__c obj1 : newList) {
            Obj2__c obj2 = new Obj2__c();
            obj2.aField = obj1.aField;
            collectObj2.add(obj2);
        }
        //Raise the flag before the DML
        recursion = true;
        insert collectObj2;
    }
}
```

Next, create two triggers. Check if there's no recursion, then call the respective sync method.

```
trigger Obj1Trigger on Obj1__c (after insert) {
    if (!HandleSync.recursion) {
        HandleSync.insert2(trigger.new);
    }
}

trigger Obj2Trigger on Obj2__c (after insert) {
    if (!HandleSync.recursion) {
        HandleSync.insert1(trigger.new);
    }
}
```

The flag will reset to false with every new transaction.